# setTimeout() problems on IE 9

Tags: javascript, object, internet-explorer-9, settimeout

I have a simple js structure like this :

```
var Waiting = (function () {

    function Waiting() {
        this.timer;
    }

    Waiting.prototype.show = function () {
        var self = this;

        clearTimeout( self.timer );
        self.timer = setTimeout( function(){ self.hideLogo(); },3000);
    }

     Waiting.prototype.hideLogo = function () {
         console.log("ok i passed timeout");
     };

     return Waiting;
})();
```

As expected, I get the "ok i passed timeout" log on every browser the first time I execute the show function (which called the hideLogo one). The problem appears in IE9 when I called for the second time the show function. This time, the hideLogo function is never called (log never appears in IE console). I tried a lot of things without any success.

If anyone as an idea...

Comment: remove the self and try using directly the this...you get the error yet?

Comment: How do you call `show`? Please post the code.

Comment: @Ark: No, that would just introduce another error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're using `setTimeout`, the function that is being called looses the *context*: in other words `this` doesn't post to the instance on which the method is called anymore. You're using `self` to cancel this issue out, but `self` is, itself, an *iffy* word (as in reserved keyword). Perhaps use `that`, and use an IIFE in the `setTimeout` call:

```
this.timer = setTimeout((function (that)
{
    return function()
    {
        clearTimeout(that.timer);//perhaps clear timeout here?
        that.hideLogo.apply(that,[]);//double dutch, the apply _shouldn't_ be required
    };
}(this)), 3000);
```

At first glance, that's the only thing I can see that might be the issue with your code: the `clearTimeout` call shouldn't be an issue, but I like to call it at the end of the timeout itself, and the `self` ambiguity thing. Let me know if this changes anything for you!

Comment: Thanks you for replying, I have tried as you said but without any sucess... I tried changing "self" to something else (like "that"), and called the hideLogo function as you done.

Comment: Oh, calling the clearTimeout inside the setTimeout function works !
I have done like this :
self.timer = setTimeout( function(){ clearTimeout( that.timer ); that.hideLogo(); },3000);
Thanks a lot !

Comment: @aIMAC: glad to hear I could help! I do wonder weather or not your code shows a bug in the JScript engine, perhaps MS should be notified, because your code does seem to me to be correct. Blame MicroSoft! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure how you'd call show the second time with the code provided, maybe you create a new Waiting()?

Here is what worked for IE8

```
var Waiting=(function () {

    function Waiting() {
        this.timer;
    }

    Waiting.prototype.show = function () {
        var self = this;
        console.log("will clear pref timeout");
        clearTimeout( self.timer );
        self.timer = setTimeout( 
          function(){ 
            self.hideLogo(); 
           },30);
    }

     Waiting.prototype.hideLogo = function () {
         console.log("ok i passed timeout");
     };
     return new Waiting();
})();
// shows only one time
Waiting.show();
Waiting.show();
// next one will show because it lets the prefious one
// finish without clearing the pref timeout.
setTimeout(function(){
Waiting.show();
},1000);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I have a single Waiting object ( var waitingPage = new Waiting(); ), and I then called the show function like this : waitingPage.show();

Comment: The code I posted above basically does the same but it returns a new Waiting instead of having to declare it outside the anonymous function. When running this it does what I expect it to do in IE8. Does it not do that in IE9? The first show() would produce "ok timeout" once because the second show() cancels the first show() timeout. The third show() produces "ok timeout".

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
setTimeout( function(){
    clearTimeout( that.timer );
    that.hideLogo();
},3000);
```

Worked for me on IE and Chrome. IE is very behind on  everything.